# Modifying datatable with custom data

Tags: datatables

I'm using datatables with flask server side, and I'm currently trying to add a mechanism to my table, such that when I select a row in the table, I send a request to the server, and the server returns a dataset that depends on the row that has been selected.

```
$('#Server1 tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
    if ( $(this).hasClass('selected') ) {
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
        $.ajax( {
            url: '/server_data',
            type: 'GET',
            method: 'GET',
            data: {
                "sEcho": 1,
                "iColumns" : 5,
                "iDisplayStart" : 0,
                "iDisplayLength" : 10,
                "sSearch" : $('#Server1_filter input').val()
            },
            success: function(data) {
                var dataObj = JSON.parse(data)
                for (i = 0; i < dataObj.aaData.length; ++i) {
                    $("#Server1").DataTable().row.add(dataObj.aaData[i]);
                }
                $("#Server1").DataTable().draw();
            }        
        });
    }
    else {
        table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        var selectedLine = table.$('tr.selected').children()
        $.ajax( {
            url: '/select_data',
            type: 'GET',
            method: 'GET',
            data: {
                "selectedDate" : $(selectedLine[0]).text(),
                "selectedTime" : $(selectedLine[1]).text(),
                "selectedType" : $(selectedLine[2]).text(),
                "selectedInstance" : $(selectedLine[3]).text(),
                "selectedLine" : $(selectedLine[4]).text(),
                "sEcho": 1,
                "iColumns" : 5,
            },
            success: function(data) {
                //$("#Server1").DataTable().clear();
                var dataObj = JSON.parse(data)
                //dataObj.selectedRow
                for (i = 0; i < dataObj.aaData.length; ++i) {
                    $("#Server1").DataTable().row.add(dataObj.aaData[i]);
                }
                $("#Server1").dataTable().draw();
            }        
        });           
    }
```

The problem is that for some reason my datatable wont redraw when I call "select_data", but draws correctly when I call "server_data", and I cant understand what seems to be the problem - when I look at the data I get from the server It's exactly what I expects to get, but the datatable doesnt redraw with the new data.

Could you help me understand what's the problem?

Comment: When you use `select_data` what is your response data?

Comment: 'aaData' array with the relevant data, number of rows in the current batch of data (filtered data), total number of records (in the original data) - same as 'server_data'